# Android Buttons wont activate

Tags: android

I know this has been asked a million times but none have led me to solving my problem. The onclicklistener will not activate the code for any of the buttons. Here are the different sections that apply to the five buttons.

```
Button btnGuysMax;
Button btnGuysMedium;
Button btnEven;
Button btnGirlsMedium;
Button btnGirlsMax;

....

private void init()
{
    datasource = new BarsDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    long id = intent.getLongExtra("bar_id",0);
    bar = datasource.getBarById(id);

    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    btnGuysMax = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuysMax);
    btnGuysMedium = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGuysMedium);
    btnEven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEven);
    btnGirlsMedium = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGirlsMedium);
    btnGirlsMax = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGirlsMax);

    ......

    btnGuysMax.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnGuysMedium.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEven.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnGirlsMedium.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnGirlsMax.setOnClickListener(this);

    .....

    @Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //resetButtons();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnGuysMax:
            //bar.setSexRatio(-2);
            //btnGuysMax.setBackgroundColor(guysMaxColor);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Max clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;
        case R.id.btnGuysMedium:
            bar.setSexRatio(-1);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Medium clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //btnGuysMedium.setBackgroundColor(guysMediumColor);
            break;
        case R.id.btnEven:
            bar.setSexRatio(0);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"Medium clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            break;
        case R.id.btnGirlsMedium:
            bar.setSexRatio(1);
            //btnGirlsMedium.setBackgroundColor(girlsMediumColor);
            break;
        case R.id.btnGirlsMax:
            bar.setSexRatio(2);
            break;
 .....
```

Comment: When/Where do you call the `init()` method?

Comment: Did you implement `OnClickListener` on you class (I guess `Activity`)?

Comment: I have other buttons that work with no problems that actually also are included later in the switch statement.

Comment: init() is called in onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a toast you need to call show method.

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something really simple like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
 @Override
public void onClickListener(View view)
{
```

instead of:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
```

Comment: You have to call onlick() when implementing onClickListener